# Updating List won't go to Before Update Trigger

Tags: trigger

I am trying to update a list of custom object, I tried putting a `System.debug` on the Before Update to know if my DML really went there.

If I update only **one single record** it shows me the `System.debug` on before Update, but when I am **trying to update the whole list of 10 records**, even one  `System.debug` **won't show up**. Only debugs on my After Update is showing, thats why my logics in Before Update won't fire. It does not give any error or such.

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger Custom_Object_Trigger on Custom_Object__c (after update, after insert, before update, before insert) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter){
            if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                System.debug('After Update Went Here');
                Custom_Object_TriggerHandler.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
            }

            if(Trigger.isInsert){
                 Custom_Object_TriggerHandler.onAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
            }

    }else{ 

            if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                System.debug('Before Update Went Here');
                Custom_Object_TriggerHandler.onBeforeUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
            }

            if(Trigger.isInsert){ 
                 Custom_Object_TriggerHandler.onBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
             }

    }
}
```

And Here's how I execute the Update:

```
List<Custom_Object__c> cObj = [Select Id, Name, Field_One__c, Field_Two__c FROM Custom_Object__c];

cObj[5].Field_One__c = 'UPDATED VALUE OF ONE';
cObj[5].Field_Two__c = 'UPDATED VALUE OF TWO';

try{
    update cObj;
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.debug(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Custom_Object__c contains 10 records. No Exception Errors are thrown. Both Field_One__c and Field_Two__c are Text Fields.

Comment: Show code, how you are performing dml. Maybe exception interrupts your transaction

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: try to remove `try-catch` block and run the code. I bet, there is an exception

Comment: No luck, no error is showing up.

Comment: I tried doing this update in Data Loader and setting the batch size to 1 - and my trigger seems to be working fine . But if I am going to set it back to 200 which is the Data Loader default batch size then its giving me the same problem.

Comment: Do you see this debug statement `Before Update Went Here` and not other debugs from your handler class ? If yes, then do you have any recursion prevention logic in `Custom_Object_TriggerHandler` class ?

Comment: I can see **Before Update Went Here** when I am updating only one record, but If I am updating a List then its not showing up. No I dont have any recursion prevention logic inside the triggerhandler.

Comment: I also noticed that when I am updating a List, the **AfterUpdate** comes first before the **BeforeUpdate**, its very weird.